# How can i access object by class type?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing WPF Application. In my application, I want to access objects by class type.

I tried below code block.

```
  public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject 
    depObj) where T : DependencyObject
  {
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

In my application, I used below way.

```
foreach (Storyboard sb in FindVisualChildren<Storyboard>(window))
{
     // There is no accessable storyboard object
}
```

I can access `Control` objects, but I can't access non `UIElement` objects. For example: I can find`RadioButton` but I can't find `Storyboard` objects.

Comment: A Storyboard is not a Visual, so VisualTreeHelper will obviously not find it. Try to set the Storyboard's `x:Name` attribute.

Comment: `I can access other controllers but I can't access objects.` I think it's unclear what you mean by this

Comment: @IDarkCoder it means controls (i.e. UIElements)

Comment: But what is meant by `objects` everything that isn't a `UIElement`?

Comment: @IDarkCoder Yes, obviously. For example Storyboards.

Comment: @MertDEMIRKIRAN: Why don't you just put all `Storyboards` in the `Resources` dictionary of the window and iterate through the resources?

Comment: Yes. Or if the `Storyboard` is part of a template and you have access to the templated control, you have to give the `Storyboard` a name (as mentioned before) and then override `OnApplyTemplate()` and get the named element using `FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild("nameOfTheElement")`.

Comment: Why does it have to be dynamic? Just the name the storyboard(s) and put them into a list or property on the VM (or codebehind on the page) during construction. Why jump through the hoops of playing hide and go seek?  I am guessing you come from a winform mindset, one has more access to items created on the view than winforms.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for your first comment. I understand why I can't access.

Comment: Guys, It has to be dynamic because i have to use much more storyboard. It's about 25-30. And I have to pause every storyboard in one event. Also i can access by name but i don't want to use like this. It has to be dynamic because maybe the storyboard objects can increase!

Comment: I think @mm8 already gave you the answer then.

Comment: @BionicCode It's not correct answer because at first I don't know how many storyboard have to create. It depends on the information from database.

Comment: @MertDEMIRKIRAN: So how are you currently creating the `Storyboards` that you try to find using the `VisualTreeHelper`? Just add these to `Resouces` instead of adding them to wherever you're adding them now.

Comment: @mm8 I creating the storyboard instance like this.                                                          
                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                        
     Storyboard sb1=new Storyboard();                                                                        Therefore I can't add these storyboard instance to Resources

Comment: @MertDEMIRKIRAN: Why not? `Resource.Add("sb1", sb1);`

Comment: @mm8 Can you post full example code the way you want to tell.

Comment: @MertDEMIRKIRAN: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a `Storyboard` is not a visual element that gets added to the visual tree so the `VisualTreeHelper` won't be able to find it.

But you could add all your `Storyboards` to the `Resources` dictionary of the window and iterate through the resources:

```
Storyboard sb1 = new Storyboard();
Storyboard sb2 = new Storyboard();
...
Resources.Add("sb1", sb1);
Resources.Add("sb2", sb2);
...
foreach (Storyboard sb in Resources.Values.OfType<Storyboard>())
{
    ...
}
```